# Common data of Free and Paid version of application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, version

I have 2 versions of application in different packages (lite and pro).
All data I keep on sdcard, except Databases and Preferenses (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)). 
How can I make it common?
And can I delete free version, when I installed pro?

Sorry, if this question allready exist, but I didn't find exactly what I look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete lite vertion by package name.

```
    Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:your.packge.name");
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Put your data on server to get json from server. That's the common way for lite as well as pro.